# I am not able to copy files inside windows directory using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, sccm

I am trying to install one application remotely and copying related files inside windows directory(C:\windows\System32).
installation is happening but copying is not happening, but I can able to copy files to other location, Please suggest a way to copy files inside windows directory using PowerShell. I am using copy-item to copy the files.

Comment: You probably require elevated permissions for your "installation", and you'd better use an MSI installer (the official and supported way of installing software) to remotely install your apps. Otherwise I suggest you make them portable, that is, not dependent on files existing in a certain folder, and have all the files in the folder with main executable.

Comment: I used MSI installer as well, but facing the same issue. But it will copy if we are executing the file directly from system. Only while pushing app remotely the files are not copying, but the app is getting installed and ARP entry got created. 
As I am pushing the app from SCCM, there is no chance of elevated permissions issue.

Comment: Are you really doing this via sccm or is the tag wrong? If so is it an application or a package and is it per user or per machine? SCCM per machine packages are run with system account and have all the rights they need, but they would always be run in 32Bit so if this were a 64bit machine the files would end up in C:\Windows\Syswow64

Comment: Please provide what you have so far so we can help. Right now we have no idea what you're doing or if you need a pull or push copy or anything.

Answer (score 0):

To work on a remote machine you can use the New-PSSession command: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849717.aspx
And to do stuff on a remote machine you can use the Invoke-Command: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx

Or you can work with a UNC Path

```
$path = '\\' + $host + '\c$\System32'
```